How to test an assembly function?
To preface, I know very little about assembly, so I don't know if what I'm trying to do even makes sense. But, I am in a class that involves reading a lot of assembly and saying what it does. Often, we are given a function in assembly and asked to write an equivalent function in C.
After writing the C version of the function (say, foo(), for example), I could test what values are outputted when I call foo() with various parameters (e.g., I could create a simple C file and print the output of foo(bar, baz) or any other arguments in the main() method).
What I would like to do is run the assembly code in a similar way (i.e., create an executable that calls the function with certain arguments and then outputs the result). So, what I am asking is pretty much if there is a way to see the result of a function call like foo(bar, baz). I want to do this so I can compare the output of the assembly function to the C function, ensuring that I "decomiled" the assembly correctly.
So far, I tried compiling the C code I wrote, disassembling the executable, and comparing it to the initial assembly function. But, I then realized that compiled assembly is not going to look the same as hand-written assembly, so this didn't really give me much information.

Yes, you can call your asm functions from C as long as you follow the conventions properly. If you use the same prototype as your C function it's a drop-in replacement. Just declare it extern and link the object file. Make sure the function is marked .global

@Jester Okay, I just did that and this seems to have solved my problem. Thanks for the help!
